# How well is source code protected when published?

Tags: vb.net, security, encryption, visual-studio-2015

I’m new to programming and have developed my own program in Visual Basic using Visual Studio 2015. When I publish the program as a standard install package (without signing it, if it matters), how confident can I feel that the original source code CAN NOT be reverse engineered from the install package?

Is it relatively easy or is the .exe file strongly encrypted? Say my program acts upon a personal login that is stored in the source code – would it be possible to extract such information from the install package? If so, any advice to protect the code further?

Hope someone out there can help.

Comment: VB.NET and vba are two different things as the tags warn.  NET code can very easily be viewed/extracted etc

Comment: ***It can be reversed, given a well-rounded engineer wants to take on the task...***. The only thing that you can do to ***help*** is obfuscate the code, but that only makes the job harder, not unbreakable... Also take a minute and check out the related area to your right (**Related**), this question has been asked numerous times before.

Comment: _personal login that is stored in the source code_ That is a really bad practice as they can be easilly retrieved without too much work, because unless you encrypt/hash them yourself, they will appear in plain text in the .exe file.

Comment: Adding a little salt will help. :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not feel confident that your .NET-compiled code is safe.

.NET code compiles to Common Intermediate Language or MSIL / Microsoft Intermediate Language.

This can be deconstructed into a similar set of .NET code that may not match yours exactly, but would allow a user to see, roughly, how the application functions.

Obfuscation would help but would not prevent deconstruction.

If you have a personal login or other user-specific data, I would recommend you replace the areas you've hardcoded this in with a User-Specific / user-scoped Application Setting instead, as these are easily managed and prevent you from shipping your finished product with your own login to a customer.

Using an application setting, you could configure a simple dialog for someone to enter this data on their own, and it would get saved for that user instead of being hard-coded.

If the problem is that you need to embed data in the application for a login that your users themselves should not be aware of... That is a very different security issue, and one that I can not answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is relatively easy to decompile .NET binaries (even for free, take a look at [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) tool). Signing binaries may only prevent possible tampering/injection, not code deconstruction. Obfuscation is the only way of making it more-or-less hard for potential eavesdropper to get to your source code internal workings. I personally recommend [.NET Reactor](http://www.eziriz.com/dotnet_reactor.htm) solution.